# Reading MetaMorph stk file failed with PIL and tifffile

Tags: image, python-imaging-library, tiff

I am using PIL to read a [MetaMorph stk](https://mdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/18862/%7E/metamorph%E2%AE-software-tiff-and-stk-file-formats) file that contains a series of cryo-EM images.

Here is the code:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('particles_export.stk')
img
```

it returns *<PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.SpiderImageFile image mode=F size=109x109 at 0x7F77085833C8>*

The stk file should contain 50 images, but when I tried
`img.seek(2)`, it returns *EOFError: attempt to seek outside sequence*, while the img page 0 and page 1 are two same page.

I've checked the stk file with ImageJ. It works fine, so the file is not corrupted.

I also tried the [module tifffile](https://github.com/cgohlke/tifffile) with the code

```
import tifffile
stk = tifffile.imread('particles_export.stk')
```

it returns an error

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/anaconda3/envs/cryo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tifffile/tifffile.py in __init__(self, arg, name, offset, size, _multifile, _useframes, _master, **kwargs)
   2754             try:
-> 2755                 byteorder = {b'II': '<', b'MM': '>', b'EP': '<'}[header[:2]]
   2756             except KeyError:

KeyError: b'\x00\x00'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TiffFileError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-d5856ab518a1> in <module>()
      4 
      5 
----> 6 stk = tifffile.imread(filename)
      7 #stk = imageio.mimread(filename, format = 'SPIDER' ,is_stk = True)

/opt/anaconda3/envs/cryo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tifffile/tifffile.py in imread(files, aszarr, **kwargs)
    710 
    711         if isinstance(files, (str, os.PathLike)) or hasattr(files, 'seek'):
--> 712             with TiffFile(files, **kwargs_file) as tif:
    713                 if aszarr:
    714                     return tif.aszarr(**kwargs)

/opt/anaconda3/envs/cryo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tifffile/tifffile.py in __init__(self, arg, name, offset, size, _multifile, _useframes, _master, **kwargs)
   2755                 byteorder = {b'II': '<', b'MM': '>', b'EP': '<'}[header[:2]]
   2756             except KeyError:
-> 2757                 raise TiffFileError('not a TIFF file')
   2758 
   2759             version = struct.unpack(byteorder + 'H', header[2:4])[0]

TiffFileError: not a TIFF file
```

I am wondering how can I read this file? I want to save the images as several single tiff files.

You may find this file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pn_RSEEfGdNPmU3QHxtzHgGqq_2ywfA1/view?usp=sharing).

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: The file you shared is not a MetaMorph STK but a [SPIDER](https://spider.wadsworth.org/spider_doc/spider/docs/image_doc.html) file.

Comment: Thanks. But I follow [PIL SPIDER](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html#spider) to read it as the code above. Why couldn't I read all the image sequence but only one of them? Is there anything wrong with my code?